# Wrong expected argument of type

Tags: php, symfony, entity, symfony-forms

I have in my model a field with the name `rank` and the type integer.

In my `formType` it is an `EntityType`, because I need this for my pulldown to make a choice in which order (rank) the new entry should be.

now of course the validation of the form is bringing the error:

> Expected argument of type "integer", "App\Entity\ProductType" given at
> property path "rank".

how can I go on with this situation?
This is Symfony 4

In the Model, I have the Field

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
 private $rank;
```

In my formType I add this entity

```php
->add('rank', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => ProductType::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.rank', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => function($productType) {
        return 'nach ' . $productType->getNameDe();
    },
    'choice_value' => function ($productType) {
        return $productType ? $productType->getRank() : '';
    },
    'placeholder' => 'am Anfang',
])
```

In the Controller

```php
$productType = new ProductType();
$form = $this->createForm(ProductTypeType::class, $productType);

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { /*here it breakes of course*/
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        
        /*Here I will set the new order (rank) to all my entries later then
          but the Form validation gives me the error*/


        $entityManager->persist($productType);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_product_type_index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`EntityType` makes a choice type from entities (objects) and returns an entity (object) and expects an entity (object).

However, `rank` appears to be an int. And thus is incompatible to what `EntityType` expects and returns. To change functionality of `EntityType`, you probably have to do some dirty hacking, that involves at least a [data transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) - you can attach one to a form field, and it transforms the data between the form and the value it gets/returns.

You might need to provide the `EntityRepositoryManager`/`EntityRepository` to the data transformer to work correctly.

It is *way easier* to use the `ChoiceType` though and just generate the `choices` from the `EntityRepository` to generate the rank values you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you Jakumi I think I give the ChoiceType a try, verry good idea